# How does 2D positioning works in Unity?

Tags: unity

I set two sprites with different widths on my scene, both on position x = 0, but the smaller one stays exactly at the middle of the bigger one. So, is the position x = 0 relative to the middle position of the sprites? Is there anyway I can set it to the top left (so my calcs would be easier)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alignment of sprites is controlled by their Pivot point.

When your sprites are single images, you set the pivot in the import settings of the texture asset:
[image: Single image pivot]

When it is a spriteset with multiple images, you can set the pivot individually for each sub-sprite in the sprite editor.

Comment: @FelipeWagner Another approach would be to offset the object's position based on it's sprite's dimensions, either manually or using a script. Very simple to do. However, although there are some use-cases where that would be preferred, the generally recommended approach is through the import settings, as described in Phillipp's answer.

Comment: Yeah, couldn't find Import Settings on the inspector of my Sprite. I'll take a better look tonight.